# How to trigger specific action if two circle meet on any of their point using View in Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-view, android-graphics

I'm doing a simple android animation using my self-customized VIEW. I have two circles drawn on the `onDraw()` method of the `class` extends to `View` class. The one circle is moving upon dragging using `MotionEvent` while the other one is static on a certain position. If the moving circle touches any point of a static circle, the color of the moving circle will change to the color of the static circle.

For example

```
int_circle_radius= 50;
int circle1_x = 0;
int circle1_y = 0;
int circle2_x = 200;
int circle2_y = 200;
```

let's assume that the moving circle which is the circle 1 was drag and drop to a certain point of the circle 2.

I tried using the below formula but the circle 1's color only change if it really goes to the exact location of the circle 2.

```
if (circle1_x == circle1_x && circle1_y == circle2_y){
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
}
```

I know that the problem here is a circle has many points from it's radius, but how can I trigger a specific action if the a circle touches any of his point to another circle? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply calculate the distance between the centers of the two circles. If the distance is less than two times the radius, the circles are intersecting. Calculating that is easy. You can not expect to get the exact `MotionEvent` where the circles distance equals the double radius, so you have to check for a distance that is less or equal:

```
int deltaX = circle1_x - circle2_x;
int deltaY = circle1_y - circle2_y;
if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2)) <= 2 * circle_radius) {
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
}
```